# How to run a piped function on start for alacritty?

Tags: alacritty

I want to run `tmuxp $(ls | fzf)` on starting alacritty, is that possible? I am sure I have to change the `program` and `args` key in `alacritty.yml`, but it just doesn't work.

This is my current config:

```yaml
shell:
  program: tmuxp
  args:
    - $(ls | fzf)
env:
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/5130) you need to spawn a shell first.

```
- bash -c "ls | fzf"
```

Comment: this works for you? I'm trying to run a script when Alacritty starts ```
shell:
  program: /bin/zsh
  args:
    - -c "/full/path/to/myScript/hello.sh"
 ```